# How to sort items by adding items into spinner?

Tags: android, sql, database, sorting, android-spinner

How to sort items by adding items into spinner? I use Sql Database for saving bookmarks in spinner. For example, the last added bookmark should be on up and must be first selected spinner item whenever i open spinner or show spinner.

```
    case R.id.showspinner:
            spinnershow();
            ArrayList<Favoritos> secciones=
                    new ArrayList<Favoritos>();

            try {
                objcon = new mysql(this, null, null, 1);

                SQLiteDatabase db = objcon.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from Favoritos order by 
                nombre ", null);

                Favoritos obj;
                while(rs.moveToNext()){
                    obj=new Favoritos();
                    obj.setNombre(rs.getString(0));
                    obj.setUrl(rs.getString(1));
                    secciones.add(obj);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            ArrayAdapter<Favoritos> adaptador=
                    new ArrayAdapter<Favoritos>(this, 
             R.layout.spinner_item,
                            secciones);

            spinner.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT column-list 
FROM table_name 
[WHERE condition] 
[ORDER BY column1, column2, .. columnN] [ASC | DESC];**

```
public List<DataModel> getAllLabels()
{
        List<DataModel > labels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT column-list from TABLE_NAME ORDER BY column_1 ASC ";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(new DataModel(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return labels;
    }

    private void loadSpinnerDataHama() {
        // database handler
        DatabaseSpinner db = new DatabaseSpinner(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<DataModel> lables = db.getAllLabels();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<DataModel> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataModel>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```